# Viewing command results page by page

Tags: unix

I use a command in AIX to view back-end nodes,etc..but they are too many so they don't fit in one page and when I run the command when it finises I can pnly scroll to last page and cannot read the rest of results in previous pages.
How can I either print the results of a command to a text file or be able to pause and see the results on other pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I either print the results of a command to a text file

Use the **redirection operators** `>` (overwrites) or `>>` (appends), which are documented in your shell's manual.

```
mycommand > output.txt
```

If you also need to redirect *stderr*, use one of the following, depending on your shell:

```
mycommand >& output.txt

mycommand > output.txt 2>&1
```

---

> or be able to pause and see the results on other pages?

Use a **pager** such as `more`, `less`, `w3m`, or `pg`.

```
mycommand | less

mycommand |& less

mycommand 2>&1 | less
```

`less` is more convenient, but might not be installed on all systems.

The `|` pipe operator is also described in your shell's manual.